# i can get the form´s select bar into a working array so i can delete it in the database?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to use php to make a simple option list for a form that can save the list in a database, the list are editable so you can add, rename or delete rows in it. I got the rename and the add to work from simple input boxes but i want to use a drop down list for the deletion sounds simple but i don´t manage to understand why it wont work so i will try to ask for help :)

This bit of code is suppose to delete the selected item from the database

```
<?php
$ukat_to_delete ="";

if (isset($_POST['delunderkat'])) {
    $ukat_to_delete = $_GET['delunderkat'];
    $sql = mysql_query("DELETE FROM listor WHERE underkategori = '$ukat_to_delete' LIMIT 1") or die (mysql_error());
    header("location: lagtillsaker.php");
    exit();
}
?>
```

and this is the code i use to make a form that shows the list

```
<form action="lagtillsaker.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="myForm3" id="myForm3" method="post">
    <table width="100%" border="0">
        <tr>
            <td width="25%">Ta bort en Underkategori </td>
            <td width="75%"><select name="delunderkat">
                <option value=""></option>
                <?php echo $grupplista ?>
                </select>
                <input name="delunderkatknap" type="submit" value="Ta bort Underkategorin" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

and i use this bit of code to generate the list

```
<?php

$grupplista="";

$sql=mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT underkategori FROM listor");
$producktCont=mysql_num_rows($sql);
if ($producktCont>0){
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
        $underkategori = $row["underkategori"];

        $grupplista .= "<option value='$underkategori'>$underkategori</option>";
    }
}else{
    echo "det finns inga underkategorier";

}
?>
```

i don´t know how i can get the form´s select bar into a working array so i can delete it in the database? I get the code to remove a string or option with no content as if the option value always is nothing in the string output.

Comment: Please set your `error_reporting` to a value that is sensible for debugging – that way, PHP itself could have told you already that you were trying to access values that don’t exist here!

Answer (score 0):

You are doing `POST` and trying to get the data as `GET`

```
$ukat_to_delete = $_GET['delunderkat'];
```

should be

```
$ukat_to_delete = $_POST['delunderkat'];
```

Comment: thanks allot were to focused on the query so i didn't think about the rest, again thank you for your quick answer !